# Backgrounded Notification from Azure Notification Hub in Xamarin

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-notificationhub

I have an Azure notification hub which is successfully sending out notifications to Android and to iOS in the foreground.

The following is my APNS template:

`const string templateBodyAPNS = "{ aps = { \"content-available\" = 1; }; Message = ${messageParam}; id=${id; }";`

This works fine and I can handle the notification in the foreground and hit breakpoints etc through the code

`public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action completionHandler)`

However, `public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application,NSDictionary userInfo, Action completionHandler)`, does not seem to obtain the notification when the app is in the background. I add breakpoints and Debug statements which are never called. However, the notification still fires in the background.

Is there anything obvious which I'm missing?

[edit]

This method is not firing when a notification is received with the app in the background.

```
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application,
NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {

        NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

        string alert = string.Empty;
        if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
            alert = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();

        // Show alert
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alert))
        {
            var notificationAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Notification", alert, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            notificationAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(notificationAlert, true, null);
        }


    }
```

This method fires the notification when the app is in the foreground and works (I take the remote notification and create a local notification.

```
public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter 
center, UNNotification notification, 
Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)

        {



            if (notification.Request.Content.Body != null)
            { 
            string[] notifdata = notification.Request.Content.Body.Split(',');

                if (notifdata.Length > 1)
                {

                    var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
                    content.Title = "New News Item";
                    content.Subtitle = notifdata[0];
                    //content.Body = "Body";
                    content.Badge = 1;
                    content.CategoryIdentifier = notifdata[1];
                    content.Sound = UNNotificationSound.Default;


                    var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(10, false);

                    var requestID = "notificationRequest";
                    var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);


                    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();

                    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
                    {
                        if (err != null)
                        {
                            // Report error
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", err);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var runcount = Preferences.Get("count", 0);

                            // Report Success
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Count is" + runcount);
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Notification Scheduled: {0}", request);


                        }


                    });



                }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: @G.hakim - Edited the question with the relevant code.